# Android Studio google play run signed android application

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-signin

I have a question.

Im new in Android Studio (came from Eclipse)

and i try to implement google play services for leaderboards and so on.

So far so good. When i upload the signed apk (maybe its important: i use the new feature google sign in) and install the app over the play store on my device, the app is signing into google play services correctly. Everything fine.

But when i come from the IDE and make there a signed build and run it directly in Android Studio, i have the message:

Installation failed.... INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION Package ....

How to fix it ... how to run a signed apk out of the IDE ... or maybe i ask why the signings (uploaded one/google play store one and the IDE one) are different and collide?

has it something todo with the new google feature "google sign in" where the keys are saved on google structure?

Some ask maybe, why i'm not deinstall the app from my device and than run it over the IDE.. and the problem is gone ..but the problem is he will not sign into google play services... he gaves the error SIGN_IN_REQUIRED

And on eclipse i remember i had not the problem. But for it i had to modify the keystore. Or do i have to do it too here and use this modified key? Or is there an other solution in Android Studio to make it all work?

Comment: Do you have different package names for different build flavors (e.g. a 'debug' suffix for the debug build flavor)?

Comment: it skipped the play app singing process on the google play console page. ..somehow. But its activated!
I never had the chance create a "upload key". I can sign the apk and upload it but it collides when i start it out of android studio (IDE).
I guess something is wrong. i never saw the page where the "pepk-tool"-button was or the other things for app signing private key and uploading the public key.
On my page under "app signing" in the google play console i only see the fingerprints (MD5, SHA-1,..) now and i have no clue what to do with them.
I think something skipped.

Comment: My plan is to go over a other google console project (where i have the page with pepk-tool and so on) and create somehow the upload key... 

but for this i need the "encryptionkey" ... but i have no clue where to find it .... because its only visible on the page before the "app signing feature" activated. And my project has not the page anymore .. only the MD5 hashes and so on. So i cant do anything i guess. Something is totaly gone wrong, i guess. Or i dont understand how it works.

Comment: or they changed the procedure? 

The other project is older ... so thats the reason that it is different? and there is no pepk-tool anymore... and so on .. and i did everythig fine?

When yes... what can i do to run the application directly from the IDE without colliding ... or when they colliding ..what ever ..how make the google play sign in process work when run it directly out of the IDE on the phone?

I cant upload the app all the time to the store ... only for testing the google play services. Thats no real workflow ... thats only hard to make progress on coding.